# How to open file and put into array, C

Tags: c, compiler-construction

```
    #include <stdio.h>

FILE *fl;
char content[BUFSIZ];

int main() {

  int i;

  fl = fopen ("data.txt", "rt");
  content = fgetc(fl);

  for (i=0;i <= sizeof(content); i++ ){
    printf("%c",content[i]);
  }

  fclose(fl);
}
```

I'm trying to open a file and put the content of the text file into content[] array. But when I tried to compile I get the following errors.

```
y:~/homework1: gcc -o hw1_2 hw1_2.c
hw1_2.c: In function 'main':
hw1_2.c:11:11: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[1024]' from type 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `fgetc` reads a single character and returns it. So **you're trying to assign a single integer to an array** which isn't going to work.

You should be using `fread` for this.

```
fread(content, 1, sizeof(content), fl);
```

However, since you tagged it homework, you may want something like this:

```
int ch;

while (i < SIZE && (ch = fgetc(fl)) != EOF)
    content[i++] = ch;
```

Comment: Thank you. `fread(content, 1, sizeof(content), fl);` worked perfectly.